# SharpDX: How to map Texture or Surface (D3D9)?

Tags: textures, direct3d, sharpdx, direct3d9

Good day!

DirectX 11 support this method:
http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-dxgi-surface-map

How do I get access to the color buffer of texture or surface using Direct3D9?

Thx!

---

**Resolved:** 
Discovered by accident, going through all the available methods. I never thought that this is what I need. :)
Thank you for your attention.

[Texture.LockRectangle](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d9-texture-lockrectangle-3)

[SlimDX/DirectX9/C# - How to access pixel-data in a Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033801/slimdx-directx9-c-how-to-access-pixel-data-in-a-texture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered by accident, going through all the available methods. I never thought that this is what I need. :)
Thank you for your attention.

[Texture.LockRectangle](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d9-texture-lockrectangle-3)

[SlimDX/DirectX9/C# - How to access pixel-data in a Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033801/slimdx-directx9-c-how-to-access-pixel-data-in-a-texture)